# Why is this happening using Multisim?

Tags: analog, multisim

I'm using the website https://www.multisim.com/create/

Why does Multisim show the current as negative above the Zener diode?

Both probes are going the same way, yet the current is shown as a negative - what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: The currents above and below R1 are different as well.

Comment: Try replacing the diode temporarily with a 1 k resistor and see if the apparent contradiction is due to the diode cathode. There are contradictions with the grey and magenta current readings as well.

Comment: With a resistor it's totally normal.

Comment: @Rohat, yes, when I connected onto the end of R1 it was normal again. I'll update the picture if I can.

Comment: I updated the picture. I created a new schematic for this, so it seems to happen consistently.

Comment: On LTspice when you click on a diode it shows "diode current" which presumably flows from anode to cathode regardless of the diode type (e.g. schottky, zener etc). So maybe there's something similar here i.e. if the tool treats PR1 as a probe to measure anode-to-cathode current *(because of its distance maybe, idk)* then it's normal to see negative readings. Place PR1 closer to top junction (much further from diode's cathode) and see what happens.

Comment: OK cool, I'll check to see if I can find anything like that, thanks!

Comment: Not found any such parameter. 

I also checked with just 3 parallel Zener's (and a single series resistor) same thing. Weird.